# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2021 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I saw the nomination phase announcement, but I didn't see any other announcements. I guess we didn't have many nominations...

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I noticed that too. It felt like this election skipped straight from nomination to a winner being announced.

Comment: @PM2Ring looking at the election results page it says "2,024 voters were eligible, 0 visited the site during the election, 178 visited the election page, and 0 voted". It would appear that, with only one nomination, an election wasn't needed.

Comment: @AaronF Correct.  on the other side of the candidate card it said:  "This election was cancelled Apr 5 at 19:57. There weren’t enough candidates to proceed to the election phase.  The following moderators were appointed:"

Comment: You're all correct. ProTempore elections for Beta sites don't have to be competitive so if there is only one eligible candidate at the end of the nomination phase that person is appointed.